# 2000 Taurus warning lights stay on, car doesn't go into gear

Tags: taurus, d186

My wife's 2000 Ford Taurus has had a couple of odd episodes lately. When she starts it up, all of the warning lights on the dash stay on. If she tries to put it in gear, the gearshift moves but the gears won't engage.

It's one of those wonderful intermittent problems that will doubtless fail to show up if I take it to a mechanic. Any suggestions?

Comment: so you put the car in gear, give it gas.. what happens? does it rev? is the engine even spinning?

Comment: I wasn't with her when it happened, but she says it was like the car was in neutral--the engine revved but the car didn't move.

Answer (score 2):

Check the on-board diagnostics code first.  If all the warning lights are on, there is an excellent chance that the engine computer has recognized the error condition.  With that information, you can make an assessment as to the next step.

You can buy a code reader or take the car to almost any shop to have them read the code.